# Tensorflow serving function using tf.Estimators causes error while calling from java

Tags: protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I have successfully created the model and wanted to export it to be used for prediction from java client but while invoking the prediction using prediction stub from java it errors out as i need to place the serialized example into a placeholder object while calling prediction!

`You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_example_tensor' with dtype string and shape [?]`

**if anyone can help me out in creating a tensorplaceholders using protobuff in java?**

there is an error as below -

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_example_tensor' with dtype string and shape [?]
 [[Node: input_example_tensor = Placeholder[dtype=DT_STRING, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:221)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:202)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:131)
at tensorflow.serving.PredictionServiceGrpc$PredictionServiceBlockingStub.predict(PredictionServiceGrpc.java:332)
```

My Signature Definition used is as below using saved_model_cli -

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
dtype: DT_STRING
shape: (-1)
name: Placeholder:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: dnn/head/Tile:0
outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify
```

Please find the code below used in java to create a request object -

```
    long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HashMap<String, Feature> inputFeatureMap = new HashMap();

    ByteString inputStr = null;

    List<ByteString> inputList = new ArrayList<ByteString>();

        HashMap<String, Object> inputData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        inputData.put("bid", Float.parseFloat("-1.628"));
        inputData.put("day_of_week", "6");
        inputData.put("hour_of_day", "5");
        inputData.put("connType", "wifi");
        inputData.put("geo", "0");
        inputData.put("size", "Phone");
        inputData.put("cat", "arcadegame");
        inputData.put("os", "7");
        inputData.put("conv", Float.parseFloat("4"));
        inputData.put("time", Float.parseFloat("650907"));
        inputData.put("conn", Float.parseFloat("5"));

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : inputData.entrySet()) {
            Feature feature = null;

            String featureName = entry.getKey();
            Object featureValue = entry.getValue();

            if (featureValue instanceof Float) {
                feature = Feature.newBuilder()
                        .setFloatList(FloatList.newBuilder().addValue(Float.parseFloat(featureValue.toString())))
                        .build();

            } else if (featureValue instanceof String) {
                feature = Feature.newBuilder()
                        .setBytesList(
                                BytesList.newBuilder().addValue(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(featureValue.toString())))
                        .build();
            } else if (featureValue instanceof Integer) {
                feature = Feature.newBuilder()
                        .setInt64List(Int64List.newBuilder().addValue(Integer.parseInt(featureValue.toString())))
                        .build();
            }

            if (feature != null) {
                inputFeatureMap.put(featureName, feature);
            }
            Features features = Features.newBuilder().putAllFeature(inputFeatureMap).build();
            inputStr = Example.newBuilder().setFeatures(features).build().toByteString();

        }


    TensorProto.Builder asyncReBuilder = TensorProto.newBuilder();
    asyncReBuilder.addStringVal(inputStr);
    TensorShapeProto.Dim idsDim2 = TensorShapeProto.Dim.newBuilder().setSize(inputList.size()).build();
    TensorShapeProto idsShape2 = TensorShapeProto.newBuilder().addDim(idsDim2).build();
    asyncReBuilder.setDtype(DataType.DT_STRING).setTensorShape(idsShape2);
    TensorProto allReqAsyncProto = asyncReBuilder.build();

    TensorProto proto = allReqAsyncProto;

    // Generate gRPC request
    com.google.protobuf.Int64Value version = com.google.protobuf.Int64Value.newBuilder().setValue(modelVersion)
            .build();
    Model.ModelSpec modelSpec = Model.ModelSpec.newBuilder().setName(modelName).setVersion(version).build();
    Predict.PredictRequest request = Predict.PredictRequest.newBuilder().setModelSpec(modelSpec)
            .putAllInputs(ImmutableMap.of("inputs", proto)).build();


    // Request gRPC server
    PredictResponse response;
    try {
        response = blockingStub.predict(request);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long diff = end - start1;
         System.out.println("diff:"+ diff);

         System.out.println("Response output count is - "+response.getOutputsCount());
         System.out.println("outputs are: - " + response.getOutputs());
         System.out.println("*********************************************");

        // response = asyncStub.predict(request);
         System.out.println("PREDICTION COMPLETE>>>>>>");

    } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

NOTE: I have used and successfully exported the model using the following export function() -

```
def _make_serving_input_fn(working_dir):


"""Creates an input function reading from raw data.
  Args:
    working_dir: Directory to read transformed metadata from.
  Returns:
    The serving input function.
  """
  raw_feature_spec = RAW_DATA_METADATA.schema.as_feature_spec()
  # Remove label since it is not available during serving.
  raw_feature_spec.pop(LABEL_KEY)

  def serving_input_fn():
    raw_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
        raw_feature_spec)
    raw_features, _, default_inputs = raw_input_fn()

    # Apply the transform function that was used to generate the materialized
    # data.
    _, transformed_features = (
        saved_transform_io.partially_apply_saved_transform(
            os.path.join(working_dir, transform_fn_io.TRANSFORM_FN_DIR),
            raw_features))

    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                         shape=[None] )
    receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(transformed_features, receiver_tensors)

  return serving_input_fn
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways i resolved it using a different serving export function()- as given below

```
def _make_serving_input_fn(working_dir):
  """Creates an input function reading from raw data.
  Args:
    working_dir: Directory to read transformed metadata from.
  Returns:
    The serving input function.
  """
  raw_feature_spec = RAW_DATA_METADATA.schema.as_feature_spec()
  # Remove label since it is not available during serving.
  raw_feature_spec.pop(LABEL_KEY)

  def serving_input_fn():
    raw_input_fn = input_fn_utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn(
        raw_feature_spec, default_batch_size=None)

    raw_features, _, inputs = raw_input_fn()

    # Apply the transform function that was used to generate the materialized
    # data.
    _, transformed_features = (
        saved_transform_io.partially_apply_saved_transform(
            os.path.join(working_dir, transform_fn_io.TRANSFORM_FN_DIR),
            raw_features))

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
    transformed_features, inputs)

  return serving_input_fn
```

**The change was get the inputs from deprecated function from contrib - input_fn_utils and then apply transformation then following with creating an ServingInputReceiver() function and returning it!**